# VLOOKUP - return multiple values/columns for one row/match of data

Tags: vlookup

I'm trying to figure out how to pull multiple columns to my target sheet when using VLOOKUP.  for example

I have a list of employees on sheet one, with 100 rows of data and want to pull details about the employee from another sheet.

From the second sheet I want multiple columns that are next to each other.  (i.e. D,E,F, and G.)

I'm doing the VLOOKUP from sheet one in column 5

lookup_value is A2 on sheet 1

Table_array is sheet 2 "A thru F"

but I want to pull columns D,E,F, and G or col_index_num - 4-7.

I'm doing them one at a time and I know there has to be a better way to get this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VLOOKUP in an array function to do this if you really want to.

There are details in [this blog post](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-excel/#Vlookup-Multiple) but here is the summary:

> 1. Select the cells (cells equal to the number of columns that you wish to fetch) where you wish to populate the VLOOKUP results.
> 2. Next, without clicking anywhere else type the formula: VLOOKUP("Florian",A:D,{1,2,3,4},FALSE) in the Formula bar. The third
>      argument i.e. {1,2,3,4} specifies the columns that need to be fetched.
> 3. After this simply hit the Ctrl + Shift + Enter keys. This will enclose the above formula in curly brackets and the cells that you had
>      selected will show the fetched columns.

Comment: For me it worked only after enclosing in ARRAYFORMULA. i.e. =ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(KEY,RANGE,{2,3},FALSE))

Answer (score 0):

Actually in step 3, when hitting "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" keys, your formula becomes this: {=VLOOKUP("Florian",A:D,{1,2,3,4},FALSE)}
Then you have to drag this formula across to other 3 Columns

Answer (score 0):

You can also query the function. It's too easy to use:
Paste this formula in `I2`:

```
QUERY(E:G,"select F, G where E='blah' "& concatenate(arrayformula("OR E='"&UNIQUE(H3:H5)&"'")))
```

Comment: Interesting but that seems specific to Google sheets. There is no such function in Excel AFAIK